# Mongo DB Grouping Queries

Tags: mongodb

I want to be able to retrieve a list of documents matching an id and trace the results back to a specific key.

Example:

```
// I have these objects: 
[{_id: 1, group: 'a'}, {_id: 2, group: 'b'}, {_id: 1, group: 'c'}]

// and these database documents: 
{_id: 1}, {_id:2}
```

I want to create a query that would return essentially {_id: 1}, {_id: 2}, {_id: 1}, or any other result where I can map back the find result to the 'group' property of the original objects.

The problem I run into is that if the list of id contains duplicates or keys not found in the target collection, I lose ordering and can't map the query result back to my objects.

I thought $group could achieve this, but I haven't been able to achieve this so far.

Comment: Can you provide a more verbose explanation of your requirement? I don't understand what you're looking for. Explaining why you want these results (what the greater purpose is) will help too. It's odd to want to write a query that returns the same documents multiple times. Also, including what you've tried already may help us understand your goal.

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of all documents matching an id, wouldn't a simple find work?

```
db.collection.find({"_id":1})
```